# Правильно пушить на гитхаб

Tags: git, github

Допустим у меня есть локальный репозиторий, я хочу кинуть его на гитхаб, мне нужно на гитхабе создать пустой репозиторий потом сделать гитклон на комп, потом переместить проект в эту папку... Но это хреновый путь, как соеденить уже существующий репозиторий с пустым гитхабовским?

Comment: Э... `git remote add ...` у вас не работает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для локального репозитория следует добавить удаленный репозиторий:

`git remote add origin git://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git`

такой командов можно добавить удаленный репозиторий на гитхабе, где origin - имя для удаленного репозитория (их может быть несколько).
Так же можно это сделать по протоколу `https`:

`git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git`

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо скопировать адрес репозитория (`github.com/example/rep.git`). В локальном репозиторий добавить удаленный сервер:

```
git add remote origin github.com/example/rep.git
```

После чего выполнить push всех данных

```
git push --all origin
git push --tags
```